# How to export a full site on an older Joomla version, transfer to a new host and update the version?

Tags: backups

I need to create a full backup of an existing Joomla website running **Joomla version 3.4.8 Stable** (I known, it's very old) and transfer it to a new hosting space so that I will be able to upgrade it.

I don't have any FTP, SSH or database account available on the existing hosting.

Is there any way that I can download a full backup (files and database) of the website and transfer it to a new hosting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Akeeba backup.

It supports Joomla! 3.4 and later.

Does full backup including database and does make it possible to transfer the whole site to another domain

https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/akeeba-backup/

Comment: Akeeba is awesome.  It also has integration with many 3rd party sites like Dropbox that you could use to access the completed backup file.